# Formula for intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table:

[image: starting table]

And now, I want to write a formula which will be:

```
 [0-5]=0, [6-15]=1, [16-25]=2,..., [86-95]=9, [96-100]=10
```

[image]

It's a little bit tricky for me, cause, first and last intervals are 5-interval, and the others are 10-interval. I wrote some code with "if case" functions, but it's slow, and inefficient code.

Edit: @pnuts here is my code:

```
=IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=6;INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<=15);1;IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=16;INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<=25);2;IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=26;INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<=35);3;IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=46; INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<=55);5;IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=56; INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<=65);6;IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=66; INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<=75);7;IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=76; INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<=85);8;IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=86; INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<95);9;IF(AND(INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))>=95; INDEX('Za Muskarce'!C3:C45;MATCH(Chart!B3;'Za Muskarce'!$B$3:$B$45;0))<=100);10;0)))))))))
```

Sorry, for one long line of the function, I don't know how to put paragraph into it.

Comment: @pnuts please, view my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for something simple like

```
=(INT((A2-6)/10)+1)
```

Where A2 is the value

Comment: Precisely! I think it is working. I will test it for all intervals, and I'll let you know. But for now, it seems that is working great! Thanks!

Comment: Should have been -6 to give correct results... thx to whoever.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either of these would suffice.

With **92** in B1 then,

```
=LOOKUP(B1, {0,6,16,26,36,46,56,66,76,86,96}, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10})
=MATCH(B1, {0,6,16,26,36,46,56,66,76,86,96})-1
```

Fill right as necessary.